How to solve this system of 2nd order ODEs by DSolve
I'm trying to analytically solve these ODEs to get $y$ and $x$
eq1[t_] := (x'[t]/x[t])^2 - 1/(3 y[t]) (x'[t]/x[t] y'[t] + y''[t])
eq2[t_] := (x'[t]/x[t])^2 + 2 x''[t]/x[t]
eq3[t_] := 2 (x'[t] /x[t] ) y'[t] + y''[t]
Substitute by (x'[t]/x[t])^2 from eq2[t] into eq1[t] and then solve with eq3[t] by DSolve at arbitrary initial conditions:
eq1[t_] := 2 x''[t]/x[t] + 1/(3 y[t]) (x'[t]/x[t] y'[t] + y''[t])
eq3[t_] := 2 (x'[t] /x[t] ) y'[t] + y''[t]
DSolve[{eq1[t] == 0, eq3[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t]},t]
Doesn't yield a solution. I think that because the equations are 2nd order in $y$ and $x$, so any help to simplify these equations and get the analytic solutions is much appreciated.

You have three odes to solve for two unknowns x[t], y[t], seems to be overdetermined I think

Yes, but one can substitute by one variable from the three equations and reduce them to a couple of equations in two unknowns like my trial. @UlrichNeumann

This leaves two equations for one unknown

Yeah, I got it .

You can not solve 3 equations with 2 unknowns, this is an overdetermined system.
What you can do is to solve for 2 of the 3 equations. You get each time another solution, therefore there is no common solution to all 3 equations:
eq1[t_] := (x'[t]/x[t])^2 - 1/(3 y[t]) (x'[t]/x[t] y'[t] + y''[t])
eq2[t_] := (x'[t]/x[t])^2 + 2 x''[t]/x[t]
eq3[t_] := 2 (x'[t]/x[t]) y'[t] + y''[t]

DSolve[{eq1[t] == 0, eq2[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t]},
  t]


DSolve[{eq2[t] == 0, eq3[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t]},
  t]


DSolve[{eq1[t] == 0, eq3[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t]},
  t]



Thanks so much for your answer : )
